# String and EditText function issues in Android

Tags: java, android, string, conditional-statements, android-edittext

i'm trying to trigger a conditional by checking the user input in an EditText field.  when i print the String from the EditText to logcat, i can see the data change, but the String functions that check against the values always return false.

```
if(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString().equals("")) {
    TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Missing Driver ID!";
}
Log.e("SMSDRVERR", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString());
```

this code always displays "Missing Driver ID!".  i have tried these other conditionals, with no success:

```
(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString().isEmpty())  //does not compile, says cannot find symbol, but the function is in the Android documentation
(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString().length() < 1) //returns false, even for strings of length > 1
```

i can confirm that the data is, indeed, no null by looking at logcat and seeing my data show up in the logs.  what's wrong with the conditional?

it doesn't fail if you insert no data in the first transmit. if the first transmit fails, all subsequent transmissions fail, regardless of whether you change the data or not. furthermore, if it passes the first transmission, it will pass all subsequent transmissions.

additionally, there are other conditionals, posted in the full code below, which also evaluate only on the first click of the button.

```
transmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //data validation
        ///////////////////////
        boolean valid = true;
        if(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Missing Driver ID!";
            showDialog(DIALOG_FAIL);
            TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Transmission Failed!"; //reset the dialog fail text to default
            valid = false;
        }
        Log.e("SMSDRVERR", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString());
        if(custSpn.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
            TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Missing Customer Selection!";
            showDialog(DIALOG_FAIL);
            TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Transmission Failed!"; //reset the dialog fail text to default
            valid = false;
        }
        if(prdSpn.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
            TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Missing Product Selection!";
            showDialog(DIALOG_FAIL);
            TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Transmission Failed!"; //reset the dialog fail text to default
            valid = false;
        }
        if(((Cursor)prdSpn.getItemAtPosition(prdSpn.getSelectedItemPosition())).getString(prdSpn.getSelectedItemPosition()).contains("CAR") || 
                ((Cursor)prdSpn.getItemAtPosition(prdSpn.getSelectedItemPosition())).getString(prdSpn.getSelectedItemPosition()).contains("AUTO") ||
                ((Cursor)prdSpn.getItemAtPosition(prdSpn.getSelectedItemPosition())).getString(prdSpn.getSelectedItemPosition()).contains("TRUCK")
            ) {
            //must have make, license# and 1vin
            if(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.make_in)).getText().toString().equals("")) {
                TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Vehicle Entry:\n Missing Make/Model!";
                showDialog(DIALOG_FAIL);
                TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Transmission Failed!"; //reset the dialog fail text to default
                valid = false;
            }
            if(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.tag_in)).getText().toString().equals("")) {
                TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Vehicle Entry:\n Missing Tag Number!";
                showDialog(DIALOG_FAIL);
                TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Transmission Failed!"; //reset the dialog fail text to default
                valid = false;
            }
            if(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.vin1_in)).getText().toString().equals("") ||
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.vin2_in)).getText().toString().equals("") ||
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.vin3_in)).getText().toString().equals("") ||
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.vin4_in)).getText().toString().equals("") ||
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.vin5_in)).getText().toString().equals("") ||
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.vin6_in)).getText().toString().equals("") ||
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.vin7_in)).getText().toString().equals("") ||
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.vin8_in)).getText().toString().equals("")
                ) {
                TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Vehicle Entry:\n Missing VIN Number!";
                showDialog(DIALOG_FAIL);
                TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Transmission Failed!"; //reset the dialog fail text to default
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        //Log.e("smsDRVERR",((EditText)smsActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString());
        //begin transmission
        ///////////////////////
        if(valid) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_TX_PROGRESS);
            Thread t = new Thread(txRunnable);
            t.start();
        } else {
            //do things if needed

        }
    }
```

Comment: UPDATE: it doesn't fail if you insert no data in the first transmit.  if the first transmit fails, all subsequent transmissions fail, regardless of whether you change the data or not.  furthermore, if it passes the first transmission, it will pass all subsequent transmissions.

Comment: You don't have an else statement.  Thus if it's ever failed, that TX_FAIL_TEXT is staying "Missing Driver ID!".

Comment: sorry, i excluded too much code originally.  posting full code below original post with some edits.

Comment: it's also crashing seemingly at random.  could this be a Cursor problem?

Comment: btw, the underlying adapter class is a CursorAdapter that points to a SQLite query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd post this as a comment, but it'd be too long...

I don't think the problem is what you think it is. However, I can't say what the problem **is**, because you haven't been clear about how you're detecting success and/or failure.

Let's start by clarifying the diagnostic code, to remove any possible ambiguities. I'd suggest you change this:

```
if(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString().equals("")) {
    TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Missing Driver ID!";
}
Log.e("SMSDRVERR", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString());
```

to:

```
final String drv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.drv_in)).getText().toString();
if(drv.equals("") {
    TX_FAIL_TEXT = "Missing Driver ID!";
    Log.e("SMSDRVERR", "Missing ID " + drv);
}
else {
    Log.e("SMSDRVERR", "Found ID" + drv);
}
```

This will eliminate any possible ambiguity in the log about whether the text really was missing. (It also makes for more readable code.)

Comment: thanks for the response.  i've changed the code to reflect your suggestion and the interesting thing is, the condition is, in fact, being satisfied.  this code actually changes a text String (TX_FAIL_TEXT) which is displayed in a Dialog.  my guess is that the Dialog is created and saved for future calls instead of updating each time the Dialog is shown.  so on the first call to showDialog(int), the Dialog is created and never changes.  iirc there's a way to have it rebuild the Dialog on each call.  thanks for your input.

Comment: @moonlightcheese: I'd bet that you're updating the Dialog in `onCreateDialog`. The problem with that is that `onCreateDialog` is only called once(!), no matter how many times you call `showDialog`. If my guess is right, then you want to intercept calls to showDialog(). Your `onDialogCreate` method should save a reference to the Dialog as a class member. Then, instead of calling `showDialog` directly, call a helper function that calls `showDialog`, and then updates the saved Dialog reference. (I hope that's clear enough...)

Comment: that was exactly it.  a call to removeDialog at the beginning of the onClick function fixed this.  thanks.

Comment: @moonlightcheese: Glad to have helped. My last comment was a little off-base, though: There's another call, `onPrepareDialog`, which is invoked for every `showDialog` call. That would save you the trouble of writing an intermediate function, as I'd written above. I gather from the documentation that Dialog objects are fairly "heavy", and it's better to re-use them within your app than to call `removeDialog`, which prevents re-use. (**EDIT**: Just saw your updated answer; looks like you'd already found `onPrepareDialog`.)

Answer (score 0):

the problem was actually with the Dialog objects.  the conditional is fine.  at the beginning of the onClick method, i added a call to:

```
 removeDialog(DIALOG_FAIL);
```

this forces Android to rebuild the Dialog the next time it is called.

EDIT: for future reference, there is a more elegant way to do this using onPrepareDialog(), but this solution was easier for me.